# Alignment problem with template and pointcloud

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I've been working with the PCL tutorials on the ROS website, specifically the "Aligning object templates to a point cloud", and I've written some code that subscribes to my Kinect sensor and publishes the alignment of a template pointcloud. The code works fine except for two issues, the alignment of the template seems to be off by few centimeters (see [screenshot](https://imgur.com/i0HXE)) and the code itself runs rather slow.

I am going to try downsample the target pointcloud in hopes that it speeds up processing time but does anyone have any ideas to why the translation alignment is off? I assumed at first it would be because my reference frames were different but the input frame is same as the output frame!

```
output.header.frame_id = input->header.frame_id;
```

Here is the callback and main code, it's mostly the Aligning object templates tutorial code with the required ROS code for subscription and publication.

```
    void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{

  // Change from type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 to pcl::PointXYZ
  pcl::fromROSMsg (*input, *cloud);
  std::vector<FeatureCloud> object_templates;
  
  // Add the Template cloud to the list of clouds
  object_templates.push_back (template_cloud);


  // Preprocess the cloud by...
  // ...removing distant points
  const float depth_limit = 1.0;
  pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZ> pass;
  pass.setInputCloud (cloud);
  pass.setFilterFieldName ("z");
  pass.setFilterLimits (0, depth_limit);
  pass.filter (*cloud);

  // ... and downsampling the point cloud
  const float voxel_grid_size = 0.005f;
  pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> vox_grid;
  vox_grid.setInputCloud (cloud);
  vox_grid.setLeafSize (voxel_grid_size, voxel_grid_size, voxel_grid_size);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tempCloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>); 
  vox_grid.filter (*tempCloud);
  cloud = tempCloud; 

  // Assign to the target FeatureCloud
  FeatureCloud target_cloud;
  target_cloud.setInputCloud (cloud);

  // Set the TemplateAlignment inputs
  TemplateAlignment template_align;
  template_align.addTemplateCloud (template_cloud);
  template_align.setTargetCloud (target_cloud);


  // Find the best template alignment
  TemplateAlignment::Result best_alignment;
  int best_index = template_align.findBestAlignment (best_alignment);
  const FeatureCloud &best_template = object_templates[best_index];

  // Print the alignment fitness score (values less than 0.00002 are good)
  printf ("Best fitness score: %f\n", best_alignment.fitness_score);

  // Print the rotation matrix and translation vector
  Eigen::Matrix3f rotation = best_alignment.final_transformation.block<3,3>(0, 0);
  Eigen::Vector3f translation = best_alignment.final_transformation.block<3,1>(0, 3);

  printf ("\n");
  printf ("    | %6.3f %6.3f %6.3f | \n", rotation (0,0), rotation (0,1), rotation (0,2));
  printf ("R = | %6.3f %6.3f %6.3f | \n", rotation (1,0), rotation (1,1), rotation (1,2));
  printf ("    | %6.3f %6.3f %6.3f | \n", rotation (2,0), rotation (2,1), rotation (2,2));
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("t = < %0.3f, %0.3f, %0.3f >\n", translation (0), translation (1), translation (2));

 printf ("Publishing and Saving \n");

// Publish the results & save the aligned template for visualization
 
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> transformed_cloud;
  pcl::transformPointCloud (*best_template.getPointCloud(), transformed_cloud, best_alignment.final_transformation);
  pcl::io::savePCDFileBinary ("alignment.pcd", transformed_cloud);

  pcl::toROSMsg (transformed_cloud, output);
  output.header.frame_id = input->header.frame_id;
  pub.publish(output);


}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{

 // INITIALIZE ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "face");


  template_cloud.loadInputCloud ("template.pcd");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1, callback);
  

  pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("face", 1);

  ros::spin();

  return (0);
}
```

Thanks in advance, this forum has been a really great help with my research!

Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40257/alignment-problem-with-template-and-pointcloud/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-07-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2014-08-04**:
Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

People over at the [pcl-users](http://www.pcl-users.org/) mailing list might be able to answer this question better. Additionally you may also want to look at the [pcl_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros) bridge. It may speed up your code a bit (or just help clean up a few lines).

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1